# Question regarding the metric tensor and conformal transformations

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, definition, conformal-field-theory

Given a metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ in a coordinate system $x^\mu$, let $x^\mu \to x'^\mu$ be a conformal transformation. Then, $$g_{\rho \sigma} \frac {\partial x'^\rho}{\partial x^\mu}\frac {\partial x'^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} = \Omega^2(x) g_{\mu \nu}$$ where the expression on the right is just the components of $f^*g$, where $f$ is the conformal transformation. I have been informed that this can be used to derive the following expression: $$dx'^\mu dx'_\mu = \Omega^2(x) dx^\mu dx_\mu.$$ Upon attempting this derivation, I arrive at $$g_{\mu \nu}dx'^\mu dx'^\nu= \Omega^2(x)g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu.$$ My questions are then: how can the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ be used to lower the indices of $dx'^\mu$, when the $x'^\mu$'s are a different set of coordinates? Wouldn't we use the metric coefficients in that coordinate system instead of the old ones? How can we then derive the expression for the line element?

Comment: Where did you read or hear about the equation that you want to show? In a book or paper? A reference might be helpful because maybe the thing that is meant is exactly the third equation you have written down: One takes the "new" components $dx'^\mu$ and $dx'_\nu$ but still uses the old basis, so the old metric has to be used still. Because otherwise the (sqared) line element should be invariant if you transform components and basis.

Comment: @unsure I have seen it in numerous places, including here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/conformal-group-conformal-algebra-and-conformal-invariance-in-field-theory.172461/ . I'm a little confused by your comment, could you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP provided [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/conformal-group-conformal-algebra-and-conformal-invariance-in-field-theory.172461/) as an example where they read the equation in question. There the flat metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is used (at least in the beginning). In equation 1.1' it is explicitely written that $ds'^2=\eta_{\mu\nu} dx'^\mu dx'^\nu$ (where I use a prime instead of an overbar to indicate the transformed objects) which is exactly $g_{\mu\nu} dx'^\mu dx'^\nu$. So the old components of the metric have been used together with the $dx'$.

This appears to me to indicate that the transformation has been considered "active". What do I mean with that? Let me explain the issue with an easy example: Our coordinate transformation is a multiplication by 2.

If this is considered as a "passive" transformation that means that we just "change our units" by this factor of 2. So all basis vectors pick up a factor $1/2$ and the coordinates just get multiplied with 2 to compensate. So if one has a vector $v$ and talks about $g_{\mu\nu} v^\mu v^\nu$ before the transformation and $g'_{\mu\nu} v'^\mu v'^\nu$ after the transformation one means the same thing, just in different coordinates so of course the result should be the same. $v'^\mu=2v^\mu$ gets compensated by $g'_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}/4$. All that should not be a surprise. We keep the same vector, just change the coordinates we use to describe that vector, but of course the vector still has the same length. This is how I know it from general relativity, where things like $ds^2$ never changed when doing a coordinate transformation.

Now consider instead an "active" multiplication by 2. This means we take a vector $v$ and form a new vector $v'=2v$ from it. This means the vector itself changes, not just our description of it. So of course the length of the vector will also change. Let's see that explicitely:

Right now we only changed our vector, not the basis vectors. Because the basis is still the same, the components of the metric also stay the same. This means when we want to compute the (square of the) length of $v'$ we take $g_{\mu\nu} v'^\mu v'^\nu=g_{\mu\nu} 2v^\mu 2v^\nu=4g_{\mu\nu} v^\mu v^\nu$. Of course this is different from $g_{\mu\nu} v^\mu v^\nu$ because $v'$ is a different vector from $v$ that we got by multiplying with 2.

Now it should be clear why $g$ is used to lower the indices of $dx'$: Because $dx'$ is indeed different from $dx$, but we use the same basis instead of the "usual case" where one considers different bases but the same object that just looks a little different when written in each basis.

I hope that gives some intuition what is happening.

Comment: That absolutely helps! Thank you very much!